# Customize Ruby Guardfile per User

Tags: ruby, guard

I am using guard and therefore I have configured my Guardfile with my host's IP address where notifications should be sent.

How can I do this customization outside of the Guardfile so that only I can see it, not the rest of my team members?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [shared configurations](https://github.com/guard/guard/wiki/Shared-configurations) page in the Guard wiki:

> If a `.guard.rb` is found in your home directory, it will be appended to
>   the Guardfile in your current directory. This can be used for tasks
>   you want guard to handle but other users probably don't.

Answer (score 0):

You have several options -- you can either read the address from an environment variable or discern it with code. However, you can probably just use '127.0.0.1' which is the localhost address and should work for anyone to point to their own machine.